# Nodejs SOAP Payex giving Errorcode ValidationError_HashNotValid

Tags: node.js, soap

thank you for your time! I'm trying to setup a SOAP connection with NodeJS to validate cards with Payex. The connection works, however Payex returns:

```
Initialize8Result: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <payex>
    <header name="Payex Header v1.0">
      <id>7e6eb2d7317c4ca5ae3bec074ed9f4c4</id>
      <date>2016-12-18 01:45:13</date>
    </header>
    <status>
      <code>ValidationError_HashNotValid</code>
      <errorCode>ValidationError_HashNotValid</errorCode>
      <description>Admin.ValidateMerchantLogon:Invalid hash</description>
      <paramName /><thirdPartyError />
    </status>
  </payex>'
```

And I can't for the life of me figure out why. As I've followed [the documentation located here](http://www.payexpim.com/technical-reference/pxorder/initialize8/). Current connection looks like this:

```
const soap = require('soap');
const crypto = require('crypto')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    const wsdlUrl = 'https://external.externaltest.payex.com/pxorder/pxorder.asmx?WSDL';
    const encryptionKey = 'encryptionkey';

    const sendData = {
        AccountNumber: 1111111,
        purchaseOperation: 'AUTHORIZATION',
        price: 100,
        priceArgList: '',
        currency: 'NOK',
        vat: 0,
        orderID: 'test',
        productNumber: '1',
        description: 'test description',
        clientIPAddress: '127.0.0.1',
        clientIdentifier: 'USERAGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
        additionalValues: 'RESPONSIVE=1',
        externalID: '',
        returnUrl: 'http://google.com',
        view: 'CREDITCARD',
        agreementRef: '',
        cancelUrl: 'http://google.com',
        clientLanguage: 'nb-NO',
    };

    const encryptString = Object.keys(sendData).map(key => sendData[key]).join('') + encryptionKey;
    const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(encryptString).digest('hex');

    sendData['hash'] = hash;

    soap.createClient(wsdlUrl, (err, soapClient) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        soapClient.Initialize8(sendData, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json(err);
            }
            console.log(res);
        });
    });
};
```

I hope one of you see where I go wrong! Thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change to
`accountNumber: 1111111,`

Ok, node solution for payex if anyone wants/needs it then :)